# Why I can't return a string from calling method inside a class?

Tags: php

I'm just studying PHP and have a question.

Here is a class that I have created

```
class keens{
public $userid, $codeq, $codetest, $qposition, $ans, $testid, $last, $keencode, $topicid, $datekeencomplete, $datenow;

function __construct() {
    $this->userid = $_SESSION['id'];
}

public function keencheck(){

    $sql="SELECT MAX(date) FROM `keencomplete` WHERE `topic_id`=$this->topicid";
    $run=mysqli_query(DBConnect::$conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error());
    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($run);
    $this->datekeencomplete=new DateTime($row[0]);
    $this->datenow=new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('Asia/Almaty'));

    $interval=date_diff($this->datekeencomplete, $this->datenow);
    $result=$interval->format('%d');

    $check=is_string($result)? 'true':'false';

    echo $result;
    echo $check;
}
```

}

When I check the $result it shows that it contains "2" and it is a string "2true".

However when I try to return $result and use it in this code

```
    $interval=new keens();
    $interval->topicid=1;
    $interval->keencheck();

    echo $interval;
```

I get the following error: Recoverable fatal error: Object of class keens could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\Ikeen\views\v_tests.php on line 16

The print_r($interval) shows following, this is not what I return, right?

```
keens Object ( [userid] => 48 [codeq] => [codetest] => [qposition] => [ans] => [testid] => [last] => [keencode] => [topicid] => 1 [datekeencomplete] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2020-04-17 12:39:51.000000 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Europe/Berlin ) [datenow] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2020-04-20 12:32:50.990006 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Asia/Almaty ) )
```

Sorry if I do something stupid. Any ideas why I can't get the return value of a function within a class?

Comment: You’re not `return`ing anything, and you’re not trying to output the return value of the method, but the entire class.

Comment: You have an error. [`mysqli_error()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) needs one argument. Please consider switching error mode on instead. [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You need to put

```
return $result;
```

at the end of your `keencheck()` function, so that it actually returns a value. Right now it doesn't return anything.

2) You need to echo the value returned from calling that function. Right now you're trying to echo your entire object, which is an instance of the `keens` class.

```
$interval=new keens();
$interval->topicid = 1;
echo $interval->keencheck();
```

Comment: Thanks, I've added return thing, but you right I echoed the whole object. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this `list()` function : The list() function is used to assign values to a list of variables in one operation.

**Note:** This function only works on numerical arrays.

```php
public function keencheck(){
    /* your code */
    return array($result, $check);
}

$interval = new keens();
$interval->topicid=1;
list($result, $check) = $interval->keencheck();

echo $result;
echo $check;
```

Comment: It usually helps to explain what you have done as there may be various changes in a block of code to fix the issue.

Comment: You have an error. [`mysqli_error()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) needs one argument. Please consider switching error mode on instead. [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)